# How to format piped datetime in a custom 24h format in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm selecting all files written since 1 month:

```
$all = ls -Recurse *mp4 | where {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).adddays(-30)}
```

and I get only time and size of those files:

```
$all | select lastwritetime,length
```

I can get the 24h format with `Get-Date -UFormat %R` but: how to get this from the last `select` output ?

I want to reach such formatting: `'dd.hh.mm.ss'` with `hh` in the 24h format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a calculated property, like this:

`Select @{l="LastWriteTime";e={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("dd.HH.mm.ss")}},length`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this -

```
$all | select *, @{ name="LastWriteTimeNew"; expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('dd.hh.mm.ss')}} `
| select LastWriteTimeNew, Length
```